# ssh hostbased access denied

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

Under Centos 7 with Selinux disabled, I can't connect through ssh with hostbased authentication.

1. Server side :

/etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
HostbasedAuthentication yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts :

```
myclient,myclient.fqdn ssh-rsa ******************
```

2. Client side

> ```
> -rw-r----- 1 root ssh_keys 1675 Jul  3  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
> ```

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      381 Jul  3  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
> ```

/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub :

```
ssh-rsa ******************
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config :

```
UseRoaming no 
Host *
  ForwardAgent no
  ForwardX11 no
  CheckHostIP no
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes
  PreferredAuthentications hostbased,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  HostbasedAuthentication yes
  EnableSSHKeysign yes
  SendEnv DISPLAY
  SendEnv USERLOGIN
```

3. ssh connection

from client :

```
[user@client.fqdn ~]$ ssh -vvv server
```

It asks the password. I see in the client logs :

```
debug2: userauth_hostbased: chost server.fqdn.
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 2
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 345666
debug3: ssh_keysign: [child] pid=331296, exec /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a hostbased packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug3: userauth_hostbased: trying key type ssh-rsa
debug3: userauth_hostbased: trying key type ssh-dss
debug1: No more client hostkeys for hostbased authentication.
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

It seems I am receiving **SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE** from [RFC 4250][1].

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Does your client have a correct "reverse DNS", i.e. is its IP address resolvable back to "myclient.fqdn"? (If not, you'll need the `HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly` option.) Are you able to connect to this system with the regular user-level publickey auth? (This is related to the signature algorithm support in recent OpenSSH.) What ssh versions do you have on the client and on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by adding /etc/hosts.equiv to the server with the client name in it.

Comment: This is rather an edit to your original question and not an answer. Please edit your question to incorporate this information and delete this answer as otherwise you will maybe not get a real answer.

Comment: Additionally, I was asking about the _client's_ rDNS, not the server's...

Comment: Yes, the client's rDNS works too.